# Limit the number of processors used by ParallelTable?

Tags: parallelization

By default, `ParallelTable` will use all the processors available in a PC. Is there a way to set a limit to the number of processors used by `ParallelTable`? For example, suppose I am running a Mathematica Script which has a `ParallelTable` statement on a PC with 8 cores. I want to limit the number of cores used by the script to 4. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the parallel kernels from Evaluation->Parallel Kernel configuration -> Parallel tab -> Manual setting

Comment: @GordonCoale This is a Mathematica script, which will run with no graphical interface.

Comment: Its worth noting that if you want to set this persistently then the you can do with code so via `Unprotect[$ProcessorCount]; $ProcessorCount = 4;`  I would presume `LaunchKernels` is better for most use cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before evaluating `ParallelTable` just launch however many kernels you want to use:

```
LaunchKernels[4]
```

By default `ParallelTable` and the other `Parallel*` functions call `LaunchKernels[]` which will launch whatever you have configured(default is essentially `LaunchKernels[Min[$ProcessorCount, $MaxLicenseSubprocesses]]`).

Answer (score 7):

To demonstrate evaluation in parallel computing on different number of kernels

1)Default list of kernels run for parallel computing

```
 `$ConfiguredKernels`
 (*("<<`1` local kernels>>", 6]}*)
```

2) Run `ParallelTable` on all kernels:

```
LaunchKernels[];   
ParallelTable[Pause[1]; f[i], {i, 6}] // AbsoluteTiming 

  (*{1.009058, {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6]}}*)
```

This result demonstrates how `Pause[1]`is distributed on 6 kernels: Total 6 seconds of pause are executed on 6 Kernels in parallel resulting in 1 seconds of execution

3) Run `ParallelTable` on only two kernels:

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[2]   
ParallelTable[Pause[1]; f[i], {i, 6}] // AbsoluteTiming   

(*{KernelObject[37, "local"], KernelObject[38, "local"]}   *)
    (*{3.004172, {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6]}}*)
```

This result demonstrates how `Pause[1]` is distributed on 2 kernels:  Total 6 seconds of pause are executed on 2 Kernels in parallel resulting in 3 seconds of execution